# Changing Margins in Stockton Beamer Theme

Tags: beamer, margins

I am creating a presentation with `beamer` using `Stockton` theme. You can find `tex` file [here](http://www1.pacific.edu/~smerz/Pacific_Beamer_Theme.html)

I have two questions to ask. How can I change the margins of a slide? For the example below, I would like to change the margins following the black lines.

[image]

Comment: The screen shots on the link to the theme don't have this black frame. Maybe you can copy the code you used for this frame.

Comment: no, it's all the same code. I just draw the black frame with Paint, to illustrate what I want. I want to take margins up to this frame.

Comment: Please I mean please don't fill the slides with text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can basically use `\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em,text margin right=1em}` to set the margins on the left and right. Just change the 1em to whatever margin you like.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Stockton}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em,text margin right=1em}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item   \lipsum[4]
    \item   \lipsum[4]
  \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But please do not use that much text on a slide, as  percusse mentioned...

[PowerPoint Presentation Advice](http://www.cob.sjsu.edu/splane_m/presentationtips.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. That was only a draft of a slide. I will not put so much text in it.